# CSS Safari element+element selector on focus bug?

Tags: css, safari, css-selectors, focus

I'm trying to use the [element+element-Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) to change the CSS for an element following a button.

The following snippet works in Chrome, Edge, Firefox - **not in Safari** for MacOS:

```css
.button:focus+.change{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>When you focus the button, the text color should change to red.</p>

<button class="button">click me</button>
<div class="change">Change color</div>
```

Any ideas, how I could resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

There is [bug in safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22261). It will not give focus event on click in safari. Instead give focus event on **TAB** click.

Or `:active` will give effect. But, upto when mouse press. When you release it will remove effect.

```
.button:focus+.change, .button:active+.change{
   color: red;
}
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/q2vj64kf/)**

Comment: Thank you for the comment. A 3 year old bug is still alive - eh ... I've built a workaround and added a hover option for the element above. "active" state is sadly no option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 'a' tag, you can just add  "tabindex" attribute to HTML tag to fix this issue on Safari. For example:

```
<a href="#" tabindex='-1' />
```

Read more about tabindex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttongroup button {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f2f2;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    height: 45px;
    
    }

 .buttongroup > button:focus  {
        background: #25a0da !important;
}
/* This worked for me in safari and firefox. ATB

.buttongroup > button.selected {
        background: #25a0da !important;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="buttongroup"><button ga-tag="input" data-value="patient" class="selected">Hey</button><button ga-tag="input" data-value="caregiver" class="">There</button></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Veda M, welcome to SO. Please consider adding some description to your code (e.g why it works, what is required to fix the issue). Thank you.